# Find 2 strings in a File and assign it to array using Excel VB

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have tried Finding a single string in a file with the help of the below code and assign the string to array

```
strSearchFor = "Call result: Successful"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("E:\Documents\logs.txt", 1)
        Set ObjShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
            strFilecontent = objTextFile.ReadAll

            arrFileContent = Split(strFilecontent, strSearchFor)
```

But now i am facing difficulty in finding two variables in a file and assigning to some array .

Example : I need to search 2 strings like "Call result: Successful" & "Call result: Fail" in a file. After searching , i need the result to be stored in Array (arrFileContent )

And also may i know how can i browse and read a file in Excel VB.
Right now , i have hardcoded as "E:\Documents\logs.txt" ,

Please help for the above ones.Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with result? A value that follows "Call result: Successful" in the text file?

Comment: Also what's the structure of your text file? I.e. are there delimiters or anything like that?

Comment: For Example : My Input file is like

Call Result:SuccessFul

-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------

Call Result: Fail

-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
Call Result :SuccessFul

So the "result" should be the lines that Comes after the String "Call Result:SuccessFul" and continue until it finds "Call Result :Successful" or "Call Result:Fail".

No delimiters as such

Answer (score 0):

To get a file specified by the user, in lieu of hardcoded:

```
Dim myFile as string

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an array from the strSearchFor string then, 
instead of this:

```
arrFileContent = Split(strFilecontent, strSearchFor)
```

you could try this:

```
If InStr(1, strFilecontent, strSearchFor, vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then
    arrFileContent = Array(strSearchFor)
else
   ....
End If
```

Comment: May i know whats the problem in my first statement 

arrFileContent = Split(strFilecontent, strSearchFor)

Does this line cause any performance problem as such

Comment: Hi, split is usually used to break down text, not to look search for substring string. For example, if you had str = "a,b,c,d" you could write: arr=split(str, ",") which will give you an array containing the letters a to d  .